# ngxs setstate first element in array

Tags: arrays, angular, setstate, ngxs

In NGXS , I need to set the new element in "items: any[]" the first index of an array every time. something like (unshift)

Example:

```
items[] = [{'aa':val},{'bb':val}]
```

Now Am inserting {'cc':val} Then expected array should be like

```
items[] = [{'cc':val}, {'aa':val},{'bb':val}]
```

Declaration

```
export class BasketStateModel {

  public **items: any[]**;
  public basketSize: number;

}
```

BASKET ACTION

```
const state = getState();

 setState({ items: **[...state.items, payload]**, basketSize: state.items.length + 1 });

}
```

Comment: can you share your reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can insert element(s) at first place in array :

[Destructuring_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) :

```js
let myArr = [{'a':'a'},{'b':'b'}]

myArr = [{'c':'c'}, ...myArr]

console.log(myArr)
```